# Converting Mysqli to PDO

Tags: pdo, mysqli

**EDIT**

```
$sql = "SELECT " . $tb . ".a
       FROM " . $tb . 
       " WHERE " . $tb . ".b = :b";

$sth = $con->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(':b' => $b));
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $row[b];
```

Wanted to also add this is just a short example of what was done with execute and the array. The conversion of $row was just a test.

Believe it or not the solution was a dummy move on my part. The solution was turning $row['b'] into $row[b]. Simply remove quotes. And all done and working. Oh and also pushed stuff into $sql so it made things nicer to look at.

**ORIGINAL**

I am swapping my code over from Mysqli to PDO. And could use a little help here.

```
$row = $con->query(
           $con->prepare(
               "SELECT " . $tb . ".a
               FROM " . $tb . " 
               WHERE " . $tb . ".b = '" . $b . "'"
           )->execute()
)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My original Mysqli that worked fine with what I was doing:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row(
           mysqli_query(
               $con,"SELECT " . $tb . ".a
               FROM " . $tb . " 
               WHERE " . $tb . ".b = '" . $b . "'"
           )
);

if (isset($row))
```

Which allowed me to do isset on $row. In the end I would like to create the PDO in a similar way that I created Mysqli. Maybe with changes also, but main concern is to try and get that code functional. Then additions can be done after. Thanks.

P.S. I know the PDO code is wrong so please don't point out the obvious. Just tell me how best it would work. I've tried learning PDO since 5 mins before this post. So go easy. :)

P.S.S. This code was code taken from mysql on if a $row existed. Changed a bit and merged by me. Then finally ported to Mysqli. And now trying to port it over to PDO. I was reading the documentation a bit on PDO. And seems this structure will also work in part for it. Its just all about getting it down.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts when people have given their time to try and help you.

Comment: @Flexo There was no time given to help if you don't mind me being forward. The solution however was silly and easy, and if it had teeth would have bit me. And that was changing 'b' to b. No quotes. The below answer which showed structure, still would have had me running into that silly mistake. Though, all done now. And I can vandalize my posts. As long as I do not harm others, or say things negatively in them. I have the right to edit them. Unless there is something in the ToS that says I may not openly edit my own posts. Which I will kindly go read now just to see.

Comment: Everything you post is posted under the CC license. The point of questions and answers is that they provide lasting benefit, not just to you but to future readers. You are welcome to make constructive edits but refrain from vandalizing them. P.S. if you solve your problem you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following pattern, which has the advantage of preventing SQL injection:

```
$statement = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id");
$statement->bindValue(":id", $id);
$statement->execute();
while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Would you have a suggestion on how to do it using a prepare and query. Like the above? To determine the existence of $row. I would prefer a short form and merging of it, as its how I learn and eventual code myself. Just PDO is new.

Comment: You can't use prepare and query together. query works with a string statement, while prepare returns a pdo statement object.